# How do you apply a custom font when using Stripe in Vue? vue-stripe-elements-plus

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, custom-font

I'm using the [vue-stripe-elements-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-elements-plus) NPM module and I can't see how to add a custom font?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin uses the options you pass in to the first element you create for creating the VUE elements.

It passes the style object to the style option when Stripe [creates](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options) elements.

It passes the `elements` property to Stripe's [elements function](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options).

In here you can add a [CustomFontSource](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/custom_font_source_object) object.

Please note, as in this example, if you want to use a Google font, you have to go to the URL provided and grab the URL within the @fontface descriptors. You would probably be better of hosting the font yourself as I fear these URLs may change over time.

```
  stripeOptions: {
    elements: {
      fonts: [{
        family: 'Lexend Deca',
        src: 'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lexenddeca/v1/K2F1fZFYk-dHSE0UPPuwQ5qnJy_YZ2ON.woff2)',
        unicodeRange: 'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD',
        style: 'normal',
        weight: '400',
        display: 'swap',
      }],
    },
    style: {
      base: {
        color: 'red',
        fontFamily: '"Lexend Deca", sans-serif',
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontWeight: '400',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      },
    },
  },
```

Stripe components:

```
          <card-number
            :stripe="stripeId"
            :options="stripeOptions"
          />

          <card-expiry
            :stripe="stripeId"
            :options="stripeOptions"
          />

          <card-cvc
            :stripe="stripeId"
            :options="stripeOptions"
          />
```

Comment: Further to this, I would add a couple of notes: If you do choose to host the font-face declaration file yourself I would bear in mind that the font files have to be hosted over https or they won't be displayed by Stripe.js. This often makes local development a bit harder as you have to use something like ngrok to serve up your local app over https. On the other hand if you choose to use fonts hosted elsewhere its worth double checking that there is no CORS policy blocking the file from being loaded by Stripe.js as that's a common issue as well.